# Can I Know the paired Bluetooth device model number of manufacturer?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I want to use two types of Bluetooth printers, Sewoo and Extech, I want to have two different behaviors, one for each, because they use different functions to print the logo.

I want the app to choose the printer object after pairing with the printer, or at any point suitable. But I don't know if I can know the printer type or model number? can I?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, did you get solution for this ?

Comment: Not really! I handled it by requesting the user to choose what printer he really has before the printing process begins.

Comment: Oh..! I am using same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first 3 bytes of the MAC address contain the manufacturer ID. You may be able to use this to infer the printer type.

Unfortunately, some printers sold under different names (and which use different drivers) are actually produced by the same manufacturer and thus have the same prefix. I haven't found a good solution to this yet.